# Android Jsoup certificate issues

Tags: java, android, jsoup, ssl-certificate

Taking help from https://gist.github.com/michalbcz/4170520 I tried to fetch html from a site which had some certificate issues.
I tried in Eclipse and it worked fine, but its giving me some issue when implemented in Android. (I am new to Android)
I am trying to fetch the value of a text field on the click of a button and trying to display it using a Toast.

This is the code.

```
package sample.app;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Date;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "sample.app";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
       Log.e(Constants.LOG , "we are here");

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     new Status().execute();
    }
});

    }

  public class Status extends AsyncTask<Void , Void , Void>{

      ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
      public String value = null;

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();

          EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
          EditText passwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
          String user = (String)userName.getText().toString();
          String pass = (String)passwd.getText().toString();
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
          SSLContext ctx = null;
          try {
              ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
          } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
              ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[]{new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
          } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
          URL url = null;
          HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
          try {
              url = new URL("https://example.com");
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          try{
               conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
              conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                  @Override
                  public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                      return true;
                  }
              });
          }
          catch (IOException io){

          }   
          try {

              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
              String input = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(br);
              Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
              Date d = new Date();
              String loginTime = doc.select("input#loginTime").val();

              value = loginTime;

          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();

          }

          conn.disconnect();
          return null;




      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

          if(value  == null){
              value = "Nothing";
          }
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.show();
      }

    }

    private static class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the logs and this is the place where I am getting an error:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

The `br` is getting a `null` value hence there is an exception and I am not able to fetch the value I intend to.
Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

This is the exception I am getting.

```
01-04 09:01:16.800 9483-14095/? E/ERR: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                                           at sample.app.MainActivity$Status.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:138)
                                           at sample.app.MainActivity$Status.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                        Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219)
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556)
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
                                           at sample.app.MainActivity$Status.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:138) 
                                           at sample.app.MainActivity$Status.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68) 
                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                        Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318) 
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219) 
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115) 
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556) 
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
                                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210) 
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
                                           at sample.app.MainActivity$Status.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:138) 
                                           at sample.app.MainActivity$Status.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68) 
                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: you silently ignore exceptions thrown by `url.openConnection();`. I guess the error is exactly at that point. If you print out the stack trace in the catch block you may get more information about what goes wrong.

Comment: Stack trace would definitely help. I'm guessing it's a problem of a missing cert or something.

Comment: I tried printing out the stacktrace it shows nothing.
It just says : 

`W/System.err:     at sample.app.MainActivity$Status.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:136)`
`W/System.err:     at sample.app.MainActivity$Status.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)`


The first one points to

 `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));`

And the second one to:


`public class Status extends AsyncTask<Void , Void , Void>{`

Comment: Try to put an `e.printStackTrace()` in every catch block (esp. The one where you're ignoring the ioException), it should say something more.. Make sure you're actually seeing all the logcat output.

Comment: I was doing a `printStackTrace`, when I tried with a `Log.getStrackTrace` I got the exception at 
`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));`

editing the question