# javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Invalid signature on ECDH server key exchange message( in java)

Tags: java, ssl, jsoup, ssl-certificate, handshake

I am getting below exception while firing simple http `GET` request from java.(actually from `jsoup java api`).

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Invalid signature on ECDH server key exchange message
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1098)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:278)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
        at com.ampower.scraper.data.util.DocumentUtil.test(DocumentUtil.java:205)
        at com.ampower.scraper.goolesearch.email.EmailScraper.doGoogleSearch(EmailScraper.java:87)
        at com.ampower.scraper.goolesearch.email.EmailScraper.main(EmailScraper.java:50)
```

Here iam using java version is 1.7.0_101. please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a expired certificate problem. I stumbled upon the same error; after [debugging the SSL/TLS Connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) I noticed said certicate was no longer valid anymore:

```
Validaty: [From: date-in-the-past,
           To: date-in-the-past]
```

As soon as the certicate was renewed, the error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

Try one of the following options:

#### Option 1: JDK upgrade

If possible, change your JDK version for a newer version and check if you run into the same issue again.

#### Option 2: Possible known issue

A [similar issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151387) has been reported. The solution comes from the using of the `jdk.tls.client.protocols` system property.

#### Option 3: Disable TLS certificates validation

```
Jsoup.connect(url).validateTLSCertificates(false).get();
```

#### Option 4: Debug the SSL exchange

Paste the url of your target site here:  [Comodoca's SSL analyzer](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/)

See the full detailed approach in this [SO answer (Wht not Java7?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35698258/363573).

#### See also:

- [Android Jsoup certificate issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578446/android-jsoup-certificate-issues)
- [getting javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version while scraping data using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35698258/363573)
- [HttpConnection#validateTLSCertificates](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html#validateTLSCertificates-boolean-)

Comment: Not one of these five links concerns the exception in the question. The problem is clearly at the other end, not this end, so how upgrading Java at this end is going to solve anything remains a mystery.

Comment: @EJP *Not one of these five links concerns the exception in the question.* They are **six** links... ## *The problem is clearly at the other end* Why? ## *how upgrading Java at this end is going to solve(...)* Can you offer a solution to OP?

Comment: @user207421 Each JDK/JRE comes with a cacerts file which holds certificates of well known CAs. So upgrading JDK automtically upgrades your trusted CA list and that's how it may help in some cases of certificate error.